# how to add multiple records to a table using query records in a form

Tags: ms-access

I have a GoatMasterTable. I have created a query "Query1" based on GoatmasterTable for specific criteria. I have converted query1 to "Query1" Form in a new Form i have few header information and used this Query1 Form to display multiple records.

I want to write header information and each line of query to a table called Medicine.

When i try to do with the below code, the first line of query repeats the number of query lines. i am not able to select second line and so on from the rest of the records from query form

**I am using the below code**

```
Private Sub exitprograme5()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Db As Database
Dim Rs As Recordset
Dim Trn As String
Set Db = CurrentDb
Set Rs = Db.OpenRecordset("Query1")

Do While Not Rs.EOF
     'To add Next De-Warming Kid Entry
     'MsgBox " Kid De-Warming Record writing"
     Dim Db1 As Database
     Dim Rs1 As Recordset
     Set Db1 = CurrentDb
     Set Rs1 = Db.OpenRecordset("Medicine")

     Rs1.AddNew
     Rs1.Fields("dateofMedication") = Me.Text62.Value
     Rs1.Fields("InjuctionType") = Me.Combo68.Value
     Rs1.Fields("Medicine") = Me.Text58.Value
     Rs1.Fields("Dose") = Me.Text60.Value
     Rs1.Fields("Problem Summary") = "De-Warming to Kids "
     Rs1.Fields("TagID") = Me.Query1.Form!TagID
     Rs1.Fields("BreedType") = Me.Query1.Form!BreedType
     Rs1.Fields("GoatGender") = Me.Query1.Form!GoatGender
     Rs1.Fields("FemaleStatus") = Me.Query1.Form!FemaleStatus
     Rs1.Fields("BodyDescription") = Me.Query1.Form!BodyDescription
     Rs1.Fields("Category") = Me.Query1.Form!Category
     Rs1.Fields("HealthStatus") = Me.Query1.Form!HealthStatus
     Rs1.Update
     Rs1.Close
     Set Rs1 = Nothing
     Db1.Close
     Rs.MoveNext
Loop
'DoCmd.Close
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
Db.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Code does not reference fields of rs. Instead of `Me.Query1.Form` should be `rs!`. Open and close Rs1 and Db1 outside the loop.

Comment: Perfectly working fine ... Thanks a lot dear .. Much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean `De-Worming` instead of `De-Warming`?

Comment: no i mean to say i changed as suggested Me.Query1.Form should be rs!

Comment: Understood, but I am suggesting word is misspelled. I am guessing English is not your first language.

Answer (score 0):

Code does not reference fields of `rs`. Instead of `Me.Query1.Form` should be `rs!`. Open and close Rs1 and Db1 outside the loop.

An INSERT SELECT action SQL might be more efficient. The following assumes fields are text type except for dateofMedication. If any field is a number type, remove the apostrophe delimiters.

```
Private Sub exitprograme5()

  'To add Next De-Warming Kid Entry
  'MsgBox " Kid De-Warming Record writing"
  CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Medicine(dateofMedication, InjuctionType, Medicine, Dose, " & _
  "[Problem Summary], TagID, BreedType, GoatGender, FemaleStatus, BodyDescription, Category, HealthStatus) " & _
  "SELECT #" & Me.Text62 & "#,'" & Me.Combo68 & "','" & Me.Text58 & "','" Me.Text60 & "','De-Warming to Kids'," & _
  "TagID,BreedType,GoatGender,FemaleStatus,BodyDescription,Category,HealthStatus FROM Query1"

End Sub
```